# Cell standby use about 35-50% of total battery?

Tags: battery, mobile-network, cellular-radio

I have Micromax canvas 2.2 a114.
I am in strong network zone and use 2g internet all time and time without network is 0%. So why it is consuming more battery. I also never in weak signal.??

Answer (score 0):

What matters is, what is your total battery life, if your phone lasts 2-3 days, then 30% is reasonable, however if it only lasts 8-10 hours, then it isn't.

If it is the latter I would recommend clearing your cache (and davlik cache if you can) and or performing a factory reset and seeing if the problem persists, also try using a different sim card on another network.

Comment: It is is d for 7 hours.happened with all sim cards.

Comment: I would try the steps I have suggested, also I would recommend testing your battery capacity with nova battery tester (it should be 2000mah)